# How to store and collect a variable in Python script using Google App Engine?

Tags: python, forms, google-app-engine, flask, environment-variables

I am creating a form that allows users to look for animal names, and runs a specific function with each button ('add animal,' 'finish').

'Add animal' run the function `meta2SQL` which creates a variable `alg_id`. Currently this is an environmental variable, which is not ideal as then only one user can fill out the form at a time without causing problems.

'Finish' runs the function `animal2SQL` which collects the variable `alg_id` and continues to use it. The issue right now is somehow `alg_id` is not being correctly stored and collecting and printing `id` gives `None`.

1. What is causing id to not be saved or collected properly, giving it a value of `None`?
2. What is the best approach to storing an `alg_id` and collecting it, so that many users can fill the form at the same time with causing a mix up of id's to user numbers?

HTML snippet, which includes my JS code:

```
<div class="section-25">
  <div class="container-5 w-container">
    <div class="text-block-6">Select the level of algorithm you&#x27;re looking to make</div>
    <div class="w-form">
      <form id="wf-form-Email-Form" name="wf-form-Email-Form" data-name="Email Form" method="post" action="">

        <!-- PAGE 1 -->
        <div id="page1" class="page" style="visibility:visible;">

          <!-- ALGORITHM NAME -->

          <label for="Algorithm-Name-3" class="custom-question algorithm-name">What will you name your algorithm?<br></label><input type="text" class="text-field enter-name w-input" maxlength="256" name="Algorithm-Name" data-name="Algorithm Name"
            placeholder="Be as creative as you like!" id="Algorithm-Name">

          <!-- ALGORITHM DESCRIPTION -->

          <label for="Algorithm-Desc-3" class="custom-question algorithm-desc">Briefly describe what your algorithm does?<br></label><input type="text" class="text-field enter-name w-input" maxlength="256" name="Algorithm-Description"
            data-name="Algorithm Description" placeholder="You can still be creative!" id="Algorithm-Desc">

          <p><input type="submit" class="submit-button-2 w-button" id="C1" value="Add Animal" onClick="showLayer('page2'), go_to_top_of_page()"></p>

        </div>


        <script>
          mybutton = document.getElementById("C1");

          function go_to_top_of_page() {
            form.action = "/meta2sql";
            form.submit();
          }
        </script>

        <!-- PAGE 2 (1st ANIMAL) -->

        <div id="page2" class="page">

          <p style="font-family: Poppins,sans-serif; color: #fff;">1st Animal</p>

          <!-- 1ST ANIMAL NAME -->

          <label for="Enter-species" class="custom-question enter-species" id="one_name">What animal are you looking for?</label>
          <input type="text" class="text-field w-input" maxlength="256" name="species1" placeholder="Enter name of animal" id="Enter-species" required="">

          <br><br>

          <p><input type="button" class="submit-button-2 w-button" id="B1" value="Go Back" onClick="showLayer('page1')">
            <input type="button" class="submit-button-2 w-button" id="F1" value="Finish" onClick="showLayer('page22'), animalSQL()"></p>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- JAVASCRIPT -->

<script language="JavaScript">
  var currentLayer = 'page1';

  function showLayer(lyr) {
    hideLayer(currentLayer);
    document.getElementById(lyr)
      .style.visibility = 'visible';
    currentLayer = lyr;
  }

  function hideLayer(lyr) {
    document.getElementById(lyr).
    style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }

  function showValues(form) {
    var values = '';
    var len = form.length - 1;
    //Leave off Submit Button
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      if (form[i].id.indexOf("C") != -1 ||
        form[i].id.indexOf("B") != -1)
        //Skip Continue and Back Buttons
        continue;
      values += form[i].id;
      values += ': ';
      values += form[i].value;
      values += '\n';
    }
    alert(values);
  }
</script>


<script>
  form = document.getElementById("wf-form-Email-Form");

  function animalSQL() {
    form.action = "/animal2sql";
    form.submit();
  }
</script>
```

Python snippet, including the two functions involved in this process

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, url_for, redirect

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
    
@app.route('/meta2sql', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def meta2sql():
    alg_name = request.form['Algorithm-Name']
    alg_description = request.form['Algorithm-Description']
    alg_metadata = mysql.meta(alg_name,alg_description)
    os.environ['alg_id']=str(alg_metadata['alg_id'][0])
    return '', 204

@app.route('/animal2sql', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def animal2sql():
    k = 20
    while k:
        if request.form['species{}'.format(k)]:
            common = request.form['species{}'.format(k)]
            break
        else:
            k = k-1

    db_user = 'root'
    db_pass = 'whalesrule!!'
    db_name = 'algorithm_library'
    db_ip   = '10.103.128.3'
    id = os.getenv('alg_id')
    print(id)
    # And then I do some things with id 
    return '', 204

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

Any advice is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not store dynamic variables in your `os.env`. Those are designed to be read and stored at the start of your app.  This is a job for a simple database to store the variables.  If your app is this simple, you could read and write to memcache, but that does not persist.  Use a simple database.

Comment: This is great advice; could you elaborate on why memcache doesn't persist?

Comment: It is just stored in RAM.  Whenever those resources need to be reclaimed, it can disappear.  It usually can last for several days, but no guarantee.  It can disappear at any time, especially it is not being accessed